# Is "communicate through writing" correct?

Tags: phrases

If they communicate primarily through writing on social networks, teenagers can lose the feeling of real friendship.

Comment: I would say so (see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76024/communicate-over-vs-communicate-through)).

Comment: Me too. No problems. Note that the antecedent _teenagers_ occurs **after** its anaphor _they_; this is grammatical, and so is _If teenagers communicate primarily through writing on social networks, they can lose the feeling of real friendship._ That's because the first clause is a subordinate clause, so the pronoun precedes, but does not command, its antecedent. The rule says that a pronoun may not both precede and command its antecedent, as it does in **They can lose the feeling of real friendship, if teenagers communicate primarily through writing on social networks,* which is ungrammatical.